# I want to display an image from a local folder yet images are not showing

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, var

this is the element that i want the images be shown

```
<div id="policyFilesPreviewContainer"></div>
```

and this is my jquery code

```
var policyFilesPreview = $('<div>');

$.each(data[0].policy_files, function(policyId, policyFile) {
  var policyRequirementDiv = $('<div>');
  policyRequirementDiv.append('<h3>Policy Requirement ID: ' + policyFile.policy_requirement_id + '</h3>');

  var filePreviewsContainer = $('<div>');

  policyFile.file_names.forEach(function(fileName) {
    // Create an <img> element for each image
    var filePreview = $('<img>', {
      src: 'assets/', // Replace with actual image path
      alt: fileName
    }).css({
      width: '150px', // Adjust image width as needed
      height: 'auto'
    });

    // Append the image to the container
    filePreviewsContainer.append(filePreview);
  });

  // Append the container to the policy requirement div
  policyRequirementDiv.append(filePreviewsContainer);

  // Append the policy requirement div to the main preview container
  policyFilesPreview.append(policyRequirementDiv);
});

// Clear and append the policyFilesPreview into the designated container
$('#policyFilesPreviewContainer').empty().append(policyFilesPreview);
```

tried lots of ways hope there is some one who can help  me with this

Comment: did you `Replace with actual image path`? when you say "local folder" is that local to the server or local to the browser?

Comment: yes the path is from my local server

Comment: and you've done `Replace with actual image path` - perhaps the *actual image path* is wrong? Do you see anything in the developer tools to suggest that the image is at least being requested by the browser?

Comment: already tried it then check as well the dev tools status on in is on 200 then theres no images loaded on the dev tool it only shows the status

Comment: are the `img` tags added to the page?

Comment: can you show me how to add it

Comment: you misunderstood ... does your code actually add the img tags to the page (you can check by ... I don't know ... looking at your browser)

Comment: ive already displayed the image now the problem is on how  can i add an image to an existing record